# How to return a filtered component from the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter

I have to filter the values based on the dropdown select. So basically I have 10 cards, which shows different state, Red,Yellow, Blue. I have a dropdown which should help me in filtering those cards on the basis of color. Let say, if i select yellow in the dropdwon, then all the 4 cards of Red should come on my screen. I have started writing the code but stuck in between. It would be great if anyone can help me with this.

```
class Drop extends Component<{}, IState> {
  state = {
    product: [],
  };
  sortOptions = [
    { value: "Red", label: "Red" },
    { value: "Yellow", label: "Yellow" },
    { value: "Blue", label: "Blue" },
  ];
  onChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.value);
    let filtered = this.sortOptions.filter(
      (card) => card.value === event.value
    );
    console.log(filtered); // It is returning value wahtever is selected in dropdown
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Dropdown
          items={this.sortOptions}
          onChange={this.OnChange}
          name="sorting"
          label="All"
          type="default"
        />

        <div>
          {this.state.product.map((product) => (
            <Card product={product}></Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside my card component:

```
<Card>
  <div> Content </div>
  {this.state.color} // this color will varies
</Card>
```

OnChange method is returning the selected value of the dropdown, but i want to filter those cards based on dropdown value

Comment: I'm surprised your code even runs. It is full of syntax errors. Not to mention formatting. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Obviously its running. I have just added the code snippet

Comment: And how does `product` look like? Does it have a `color` property?

Comment: product is just a card with the name on top of it as Red, Blue, Yellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have your filtering in the wrong place.

First you'll want to track the selected color in state:

```
state = { products: [], color: 'Red' }
```

Now allow your change handler to update that state:

```
onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ color: event.value })
}
```

Now you can filter based on what's selected in `render()` with something like:

```
    <div>
      {this.state.products
        .filter(product => product.color == this.state.color)
        .map(product => <Card product={product} />)}
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey Alex, On click of dropdown I want the filter to work or else normal all the cards will display on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but this is only a starting point for you. Change the logic in the `filter()` call to work how you need it to.